# Regex \s\s matches `return + place`

Tags: javascript, regex, ascii

I have constructed a string as follows

```
let str = String.fromCharCode(13) + ' ';
```

Next, I would like to know if the string contains two spaces

```
str.match(/\s\s/)
```

The weird thing is that it is a match. But if I do

```
str.match(/  /)
```

it isn't. Can someone explain to me why this is happening ?

Comment: A space in a regex pattern (matches a regular space) is not the same as `\s` (any whitespace).

Comment: see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for example. `\s` is equivalent to  `[ \t\r\n\f]`. In other words, it matched space, tab, new line, form feed and carriage return. Note it might vary slightly with different flavors of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '\s' pattern allows you to match any kind of whitespace, not just space itself. For a more detailed list you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for example.

For reference (copied from the developer reference):

> Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form
>   feed, line feed and other Unicode spaces. Equivalent to [
>   \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff].
>
> For example, /\s\w*/ matches " bar" in "foo bar".